# How does this code not cause an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, express, graphql

So, this is a different question from what you usually read.
I followed a GraphQL express tutorial and saw the following snippet.

```js
const getUser = async userId => {
    const user = await User.findById(userId);

    return {
        ...user._doc,
        password: null,
        _id: user.id,
        createdEvents: getEvents.bind(this, user._doc.createdEvents),
    }
}

const getEvents = async eventIds => {
    const events = await Event.find({_id: { $in: eventIds }})

    return events.map(event => {
        return {
            ...event._doc,
            _id: event.id,
            date: new Date(event._doc.date).toISOString(),
            creator: getUser.bind(this, event.creator)
        }
    })
}

module.exports = {
    events: async () => {
        const events = await Event.find();

        return events.map(event => {
            return {
                ...event._doc,
                _id: event.id,
                date: new Date(event._doc.date).toISOString(),
                creator: getUser.bind(this, event._doc.creator),
            }
        })
    },
 }
```

How does this not cause an infinite loop?

Comment: Why might it cause an infinite loop?

Comment: Because the first 2 functions call each other. Unless I am misunderstanding the .bind method...

Comment: You are misunderstanding the `.bind()` function. It returns a new function but it doesn't call the function on which it's called.